# Is there a speed limit on JLists?

Tags: java, swing, jlist, event-dispatch-thread

I'm baffled. With extensive testing I can confirm that if I add objects faster than y to the DefaultListModel connected to the JList, the JList dissapears.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
JPanel pane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
JList<LogMessage> messageList = new JList<LogMessage>(dataModel.getMessageList());
pane.add(messageList , BorderLayout.CENTER);

//add pane to JFrame etc.
```

After initializing the GUI I add 100 LogMessages to the DefaultListModel. What's strange is that everything works if I do Thread.sleep(10); between each of the 100 new LogMessages. If I don't - the JList vanishes.

I tried to export as a runnable jar and run it - the problem was gone. I still need to be able to run run my programs from eclipse though.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Are you adding to the `ListModel` in the Swing event thread?

Comment: Steve: No, I do everything on startup.

Comment: That is most likely your problem. Take a look at `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable)

Comment: You are probably accessing Swing components on a different thread other than the EDT , which causes the error

Comment: I just confirmed that you're both right. It worked when updating ListModel with SwingUtilities.invokeLater. Post an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All Swing Components should only be accessed on the `Event Dispatch Thread` or the `EDT` in short. If not then you are violating the swing threading principles, and you may encounter strange errors like the one you got.

To post a task(i.e. a `Runnable`) to be queued to run on the EDT use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`